# Time Frequency of Inserts

Tags: mysql

I have data being inserted into a mysql table of the form

```
id     companyid     date
```

how would I find the time average frequency of inserts by companyid.

Some companies send data daily, some weekly, some every 10 days, etc.

would like a result of the form

```
companyid     average frequency of inserts
2       every 5 days
3       every 10 days
4       every 2 days
```

Answer (score 2):

One definition of average would be the difference between the maximum and minimum values divided by one less than the count.  Something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
select companyid,
       (case when max(date) <> min(date())
             then datediff(max(date), min(date)) / (count(*) - 1)
        end) as average_frequency
from table t
group by companyid;
```

Comment: thanks, great answer. is there some kind of statistical function in mysql to improve the accuracy in case one unusual record throws everything off.

Comment: @RayS. . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.  That would be a different question.